# Unexpected behaviour with GLSL Matrix

Tags: opengl, glsl

The following simple fragment shader exhibits very odd behaviour. Without the loop the output is all red, as expected. But with the loop it turns yellow, i. e. rgb(1,1,0). Might someone enlighten me as to what is happening here?

```
void main(void)
{
    mat4 redUnit = mat4(
        1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0,
        1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0,
        1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0,
        1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0
    );
    mat4 greenUnit = mat4(
        0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
        0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
        0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
        0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0
    );
    mat4 blueUnit = mat4(
        0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
        0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
        0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
        0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0
    );

    for (int x = -1; x < 3; x++) {
        for (int y = -1; y < 3; y++) {
            redUnit[x+1][y+1] = 1.0;
            greenUnit[x+1][y+1] = 0.0;
            blueUnit[x+1][y+1] = 0.0;
        }
    }

    gl_FragColor = vec4(redUnit[0][0], greenUnit[0][0], blueUnit[0][0], 1.0);
}
```

EDIT: The output color depends on the order in which the variables are declared. So somehow memory boundaries are being violated. Still doesn't explain the behaviour though.

Comment: OS?  GL implementation vendor?  `#version` directive?

Comment: Windows 7 32bit, Intel (OpenGL 2.0), no #version directive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case anyone else encounters this: It is a bug in the Intel GMA graphics driver. On another machine with a different graphics card everything works just fine.